# $.ajax POST prompting authentication dialog

Tags: ajax, post

I am trying to call a WebMethod using AJAX POST but the browser keeps opening an 'authentication dialog'. I've not encountered this problem before using similar code detailed below.

In my search.aspx file I have the following:

HTML

```
<a href="javascript: ExpandChild('div4');" runat="server"> <img alt="Students" id="imgdiv4" src="images/arrow-right-b.png" />
</a>
```

JS

```
function ExpandChild(input)
{ 
    //somethings are done here 
    LoadStudentData(); 
}

function LoadStudentData()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'webmethods.aspx/TestCall',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("ajax called");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("An unknown error occurred, please try again: " + result.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

In my webmethods.aspx file I have the following:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string TestCall()
{
    return "it worked";
}
```

I know the code gets the to the LoadStudentData method but I have no idea why it is then opening an authentication dialog. Both the search.aspx page and the webmethods.aspx page are in the root of my project

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and this problem occurs in Chrome and Firefox when run on my local machine. When debugging the code it never gets to the TestCall method.

Any help much apprecciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this article
http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/105222/Error-SystemInvalidOperationException-Authentication-failed/

In the App_start/RouteConfig.cs I changed

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

To

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

Then the ajax post worked fine.